# Better way to write PL/pgSQL?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Is there a decent IDE-like tool for writing and debugging PL/pgSQL functions, e.g. for writing stored procedures?

I find it an exercise in frustration using pgAdmin III, because the error messages are often deeply cryptic and things have a habit of failing in mysterious ways.

Comment: Rob>  Have you found anything suitable for your pgsql development needs? I shared your pains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those products list PL/pgSQL Debugger as a feature: [PostgreSQL Maestro](http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/postgresql/maestro/screenshots/getting_started/pgsql_debugger/), [EMS SQL Manager for PostgreSQL](http://www.sqlmanager.net/products/postgresql/manager/screenshots/1570), [Postgres Plus® Advanced Server](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products/postgres_plus_as/overview.do#ui-tabs-77).

I haven't used any of them though.

Comment: All are paid? There is no one free?

Comment: You can make use of that debugger in PgAdmin.

Answer (score 4):

I using classic programmer editor like emacs, vi, eclipse. I have one rule: store every code to file. Classic editors are usually better tools for editing code than DBA specialised IDE managers. psql has important command \i file for import edited file to PostgreSQL.

p.s. Emacs has very nice support for sql and is very well integrated with Postgres.

My second rule - don't use GUI managers for editing stored procedures. You cannot comment code, you have not control over sources. You cannot put related procedures to one file. IDE allows editing only isolated procedures, and it is very bad - for maintenance more than ten procedures.

Comment: This is definitely the way to go with stored procedures. I've had PostgreSQL and Oracle dev, test and live databases fail and I always store code first in the filesystem as a file, second in a version control (CVS,svn,git,whatever that may be) I use Notepad++ in windows mostly -- just because it's highly configurable (custom plugins and shortcuts) and portable across different Windows hosts.

Answer (score 1):

Quite extensive list of DBA tools you can find here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_database_tools.

I can recommend with a clear conscience Aqua Data Studio - for writing and debugging PL/pgSQL functions it's just great. But unfortunately it is not free.